# pandas, how to merge tow dataframe with multiple columns IDs

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

Sorry, I am new with pandas and I'm struggling.
Basically, I have two dataset
df1:

| sites | nb samples |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |

df2:

| sites1 | sites2 | nb links |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 3 |
| A | C | 1 |

What I want to get is
output:

| sites1 | sites2 | nb links | nb samples sites1 | nb samples sites2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| A | C | 1 | 3 | 1 |

I tried several things like:

`print(pd.merge(df2,df1 ,left_on='sites1',right_on=['sites']))`

But iam far away from the result I want to get.

Many thanks in advance for some helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-liner using [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and `.rename()`

```
df_new = df2.merge(df1, left_on='sites1', right_on='sites', how='left').merge(df1, left_on='sites2', right_on='sites', how='left')[['sites1', 'sites2', 'nb links', 'nb samples_x', 'nb samples_y']].rename(columns={'nb samples_x': 'nb samples sites1', 'nb samples_y': 'nb samples sites2'})

[Out]:

  sites1 sites2  nb links  nb samples sites1  nb samples sites2
0      A      B         3                  3                  2
1      A      C         1                  3                  1
```

---

**Notes**

- Let us break down to make it easier to understand:

  1. One starts by merging both dataframes

     ```
     df_new = df2.merge(df1, left_on='sites1', right_on='sites', how='left').merge(df1, left_on='sites2', right_on='sites', how='left')

     [Out]:

       sites1 sites2  nb links sites_x  nb samples_x sites_y  nb samples_y
     0      A      B         3       A             3       B             2
     1      A      C         1       A             3       C             1
     ```
  2. Selecting only the columns one wants to consider

     ```
     df_new = df_new[['sites1', 'sites2', 'nb links', 'nb samples_x', 'nb samples_y']]

     [Out]:

       sites1 sites2  nb links  nb samples_x  nb samples_y
     0      A      B         3             3             2
     1      A      C         1             3             1
     ```
  3. Renaming the columns

     ```
     df_new.columns = ['sites1', 'sites2', 'nb links', 'nb samples sites1', 'nb samples sites2']

     [Out]:

       sites1 sites2  nb links  nb samples sites1  nb samples sites2
     0      A      B         3                  3                  2
     1      A      C         1                  3                  1
     ```

Comment: Many thanks, it's amazing. I really appreciated it that you explained each step. However, one things that I am not sure to get. For example, the header "nb samples_x" has been generated automatically?

Comment: @Pierre yes. `suffixes` is one of the parameters one can pass with `pandas.DataFrame.merge`. It is a list-like, and default is `(“_x”, “_y”)`. They are a way to prevent clashes in columns with the same names in left and right respectively. Read more about it in the [Official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).